# How to draw single-colour Ellipse (no black border) with QPainter

Tags: c++, qt, qpainter, drawellipse

Code for the beginning:

```
QColor yellow("#f0d048");
Qt::BrushStyle style = Qt::SolidPattern;
QBrush brush(yellow, style);
painter.setBrush(brush);
painter.drawEllipse(10,10,10,10);
```

Everytime I do this, I get a yellow circle surrounded by a black 1-pixel-sized border. In total the circle will have the same size like if I draw with black colour, so what shall I do to just get a single-coloured yellow circle without black border?

Best regards

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Set a pen on painter

```
painter.setPen(Qt::NoPen);
```

Qt has 'brush' for filling figures, and 'pen' for drawing lines and outlines.

Comment: Thank you, I just now realized that basically every shape has an outline which seems to be black as standard, so the pen-setting can "overwrite" this to any colour (or nothing)

Comment: In my case, setting pen to `Qt::NoPen` didn't solve the issue, but setting it to a transparent color (i.e. `QColor(0,0,0,0)`) did. Your emphasize on the distinction between Qt's notion of brushes and pens is very much appreciated. Thanks.